# How to get rid of rom-boot & network boot options when booting up

Tags: windows-7, boot

I am using a compaq b1200. And it really sucks when you boot up and see those choices consuming a lot of time in the boot process. How do I get rid of it to achieve faster boot up. In windows, specifically windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into the BIOS and change the boot device list. Restrict it to just the hard drive, or maybe the hard drive and the CD-ROM device. This should stop the BIOS waiting on those boot devices on startup.